# Add popup to marker added by DrawToolbar in leaflet shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a shiny app, where a user can create new points on a leaflet map via the DrawToolbar. Each time a new marker is set, the coordinates are added to a data.frame. I want to show these coordinates as a popup of the newly added markers. Is this possible without loosing the possibility to drag or remove the new markers?

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)

data <- data.frame(lat = c(), lon = c())

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      addDrawToolbar(
        targetGroup = "new_points",
        polylineOptions = FALSE,
        polygonOptions = FALSE,
        rectangleOptions = FALSE,
        circleOptions = FALSE,
        editOptions = editToolbarOptions(selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions()))
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_draw_new_feature, {
    click_lat <- input$map_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[2]]
    click_lon <- input$map_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[1]]
    data <- rbind(data, cbind(click_lat, click_lon))
    print(data)
  })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reactiveValues` instead of a global variable to store the new markers, it will replot the map (adding all markers with popup) every time you add one:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactiveValues(lat = NULL, lon = NULL)
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    # Get setView parameters
    new_zoom <- 2
    if(!is.null(input$map_zoom)) new_zoom <- input$map_zoom
    new_lat <- 0
    if(!is.null(input$map_center$lat)) new_lat <- input$map_center$lat
    new_lon <- 0
    if(!is.null(input$map_center$lng)) new_lon <- input$map_center$lng

    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(new_lon,new_lat,zoom = new_zoom) %>% 
      addDrawToolbar(
        targetGroup = "new_points",
        polylineOptions = FALSE,
        polygonOptions = FALSE,
        rectangleOptions = FALSE,
        circleOptions = FALSE,
        editOptions = editToolbarOptions(
          selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions()))-> map

    if (!is.null(data$lat)) {
       addMarkers(map, lng=data$lon, lat=data$lat, 
          popup=paste("lat=", data$lat, ", lon=", data$lon))}
    else map
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_draw_new_feature, {
    click_lat <- input$map_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[2]]
    click_lon <- input$map_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates[[1]]
    data$lat <- c(data$lat,click_lat)
    data$lon <- c(data$lon,click_lon)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Notice the `setView` call to avoid zooming to the first marker you add

Comment: Is there a way to do this without loosing the possibility to drag or remove the markers? In my case the popups should help to choose, which markers have been added incorrectly, so these could be dragged or deleted. I will also update my question to make this clear.